# Align Android XML attributes in a single column only

Tags: android, xml

How do I force Android Studio to align XML attributes in a single column only?

For example, this happens by default which is really annoying as I always have to manually reformat each view:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vImg"
    android:layout_width="24dp" android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

But I want it to be like this by default or at least by pressing Ctrl+Alt+L:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vImg"
    android:layout_width="24dp" 
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```